# Google Chrome Headless Error "Not supported" When using getDisplayMedia trying to record screen from Chrome Tab in Puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, headless, google-chrome-headless, screen-capture

I am using Puppeteer latest version with Chromium 80 and I'm trying to record video from page in chrome headless and turned on all these flags:

```
{
  headless: true,
  devtools: false,
  args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--allow-insecure-localhost',
    '--enable-usermedia-screen-capturing',
    '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream', // In headless: false it will capture display rather than tab and in headless: true doesn't work
    '--auto-select-desktop-capture-source=[RECORD]', //[RECORD] is the title of my localhost page trying to screen capture
    '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
    '--window-size=1440,900',
  ],
  ignoreDefaultArgs: [
    '--mute-audio',
    '--disable-media-session-api',
  ]
}
```

On windows if this is `headless : false` it will capture the chrome tab (sometimes crashes). But if this is `headless : true` even on Windows it says it is `Not supported`.
If `--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream` flag is on then it is another story and it will capture one of my displays regardless of being `headless` true or false.

Now I want to use this on my linux server where there is no display and I just want the chrome `headless : true` to capture my chrome tab. I know it can do that because I can see the screen in `headless : true` mode in the DevTools. If it is creating a display on DevTools it MUST be able to create the display on screen capture. I suppose there must be other flags to be turned on on Puppeteer so it is allowed to do so. I am using `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` in order to get the screen data.

I also have tried this video configuration and it didn't work (crashed) and apparently only works on extensions and I need to get source id from background:

```
screenStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
        video: {
            //mandatory: {
            //    chromeMediaSource: 'tab', // Not using this!
            //}
        },
        audio: false
});
```

Is there anyone that knows what flags should be also considered into the Puppeteer?

Please Note that I don't want to use xvfb and Selenium (WebDrive) or any extensions in my chrome headless.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing in order to debug a failing test in CI.

Comment: Not really, But I think the best way of doing it is to take screenshots frame by frame and convert it to video by ffmpeg. That's the only way that I could come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is reported as a bug [Here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1195881&q=Headless%20%20getDisplayMedia&can=2) and also people on GitHub are having same issue. it seems its a bug and it's not clear when they are going to fix it.

In the meantime you can use [`puppeteer-video-recorder` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-video-recorder) which apparently works in headless and headful mode.

> **Does it record videos in headless Chrome?**
>
> Yes it does.

But since it uses `FFMPEG` the creation of the video seems to be slow.
anyways, I hope you can use it and it helps you.

Comment: Anyone looking to solve this should go and [star the issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1195881&q=Headless%20%20getDisplayMedia&can=2) to show Chromium team that `getDisplayMedia` is needed in headless.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had this issue on March 2020 and I should have raised the issue with the Chromioum team but I decided to fix my problem in another way which apparently now is a puppeteer extension created by someone else. I am disappointed on myself why I didn't try to share my solution as a extension or alert the chromium team. Hopefully this will be a teaching lesson for me to be more active in the community. Thank you for the response. :)